# Updating default R version on Rstudio server

Tags: r, blas, rstudio-server

I'm trying to setup BLAS on my system which had R 3.2.3.

I downloaded R-3.4.2.tar.gz then extracted and configured the new version of R.

Finally, I added a following line to "/etc/rstudio/profiles"

```
r-version = /opt/R/YOUR_VERSION/bin/R
```

But older version of R still shows up.

How can I change my R to newer one in RStudio Server?

Comment: Wow! A post from the future. There is no R 4.3.2 yet. Also, how is this related to the BLAS? You can configure your R version in the RStudio menu (Tools --> Global Options on my system).

Comment: My mistake, LOL!  It is 3.4.2. Anyway, the option is not available in RStudio sever. How can I do that in linux terminal?

Comment: Did you replace `YOUR_VERSION` with the version string, i.e., did you use the correct path?